# Iterate Map entries inside match statement

Tags: scala

I am writing equals method for a Scala class where accumUpdates is of Map[Long, Any].
I tried the following:

```
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: DirectTaskResult[_] if (!this.valueBytes.equals(that.valueBytes)) => false
    case that: DirectTaskResult[_] if (this.accumUpdates.size != that.accumUpdates.size) => false
    case that: DirectTaskResult[_] => {
      for ((key, value) <- this.accumUpdates) {
        if (!value.equals(that.accumUpdates.get(key))) false
      }
    }
    case _ => false
  }
```

The above gave me:

```
TaskResult.scala:53: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]       for ((key, value) <- this.accumUpdates) {
[error]                         ^
[error] one error found
```

Can someone provide hint as to how the Map entries can be iterated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
value.filter(value => value._2.equals(value1.get(value._1))).isEmpty
```

Reason you get error is, with condition getting satisfied, you will return false, but what if your condition evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this is you want to do?

```
case class DirectTaskResult(accumUpdates: Map[Long, Any])

object IterateMap {
  val accumUpdates = Map[Long, Any](1L -> "one", 2L -> 2, 3L -> 3)

  def thirdCaseClauseOfEquals(that: DirectTaskResult) = {
    accumUpdates.keys.forall { key =>
      accumUpdates.get(key) == that.accumUpdates.get(key)
    }
  }
}
```

It succeeds with this tests:

```
val t = Map[Long, Any](1L -> "one", 2L -> 2, 3L -> 3)

assert(IterateMap.thirdCaseClauseOfEquals(DirectTaskResult(t)) == true)
assert(IterateMap.thirdCaseClauseOfEquals(DirectTaskResult(t + (4L -> "Four"))) == true)
assert(IterateMap.thirdCaseClauseOfEquals(DirectTaskResult(t - 1L)) == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iterating over the map values is fine, but your for-loop is not. For-loop always returns `Unit`. If you want to return something else than Unit, you must use for-yield construct. The other answers showed how to reformulate it - I especially like the solution with `forAll` which already has a for-loop built in.

Here is illustration of the difference between for and for-yield

```
scala> def a(mym:Map[_,_]) = {for ((k,v)<-mym)  k}
a: (mym: Map[_, _])Unit

scala> def a(mym:Map[_,_]) = {for ((k,v)<-mym)  yield k}
a: (mym: Map[_, _])scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Any]
```